# DAX query for calculating percentage of sales in Direct Query Mode in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a requirement where i have to summarise the sales data by department and then create a calculated column to show the percentage of how much each department had contributed towards total sales.

[image: The layout of Desired Table]

Here % should be the calculated column in Direct Query Mode

Comment: I think you want a measure, not a calculated column.

Comment: Can you suggest something that I can do with measure, I have tried all the solution available online which were similar to my problem but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide much information or what you have already tried, I can't really guess your model, but I hope this gives you a starting point.

Create a new measure:

*(replace the table name where needed)*

```
% Sales Sub Category = DIVIDE(
        SUM('Sales'[Sales]),
        CALCULATE(SUM('Sales'[Sales]), ALL('Sales'[Sub Category])
    )
```

[image: Example with Adventure Works]